# Problem with YAML on Lunar VIM in Windows

Tags: neovim, treesitter, lunarvim

Hello I was 3 hours trying to solve this issue by my own but I did not arrive in a solution, everytime that I open a project with yaml give this error:

Error executing vim.schedule lua callback: Failed to load parser for language 'yaml': uv_dlopen: The specified procedure could not be found.

stack traceback:
[C]: in function '_ts_add_language'
...eovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:99: in function 'add'
...m/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/languagetree.lua:98: in function 'new'
...m Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:61: in function '_create_parser'
...m Files/Neovim/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:131: in function 'get_parser'
...zy/opt/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/previewers/utils.lua:141: in function 'ts_highlighter'
...zy/opt/telescope.nvim/lua/telescope/previewers/utils.lua:119: in function 'highlighter'
...scope.nvim/lua/telescope/previewers/buffer_previewer.lua:244: in function 'cb'
vim/_editor.lua:263: in function <vim/_editor.lua:262>

vim.treesitter: require("vim.treesitter.health").check()

Nvim runtime ABI version: 14
OK Parser: comment    ABI: 13, path: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Roaming\lunarvim\site\pack\lazy\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\comment.so
ERROR Parser "html" failed to load (path: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Roaming\lunarvim\site\pack\lazy\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\html.so): Failed to load parser for language 'html': uv_dlopen: The specified procedure could not be found.

OK Parser: json       ABI: 14, path: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Roaming\lunarvim\site\pack\lazy\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\json.so
OK Parser: lua        ABI: 13, path: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Roaming\lunarvim\site\pack\lazy\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\lua.so
OK Parser: markdown_inline ABI: 13, path: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Roaming\lunarvim\site\pack\lazy\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\markdown_inline.so
OK Parser: regex      ABI: 13, path: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Roaming\lunarvim\site\pack\lazy\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\regex.so
OK Parser: tsx        ABI: 14, path: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Roaming\lunarvim\site\pack\lazy\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\tsx.so
OK Parser: typescript ABI: 14, path: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Roaming\lunarvim\site\pack\lazy\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\typescript.so
ERROR Parser "yaml" failed to load (path: C:\Users\juanc\AppData\Roaming\lunarvim\site\pack\lazy\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\yaml.so): Failed to load parser for language 'yaml': uv_dlopen: The specified procedure could not be found.

OK Parser: c          ABI: 13, path: C:\Program Files\Neovim\lib\nvim\parser\c.dll
OK Parser: lua        ABI: 13, path: C:\Program Files\Neovim\lib\nvim\parser\lua.dll
OK Parser: query      ABI: 14, path: C:\Program Files\Neovim\lib\nvim\parser\query.dll
OK Parser: vim        ABI: 14, path: C:\Program Files\Neovim\lib\nvim\parser\vim.dll
OK Parser: vimdoc     ABI: 14, path: C:\Program Files\Neovim\lib\nvim\parser\vimdoc.dll

I tried to

- download and install clang
- uninstall and install gain Lunar VIM
- restart machine
- Manually install YAML with  `TSInstall yaml`
- Tried some configurations also on lua.config but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the default treesitter parser

`:TSUninstall yaml`
And then install it directly from plugin add this to your `confg.lua`

```
require'nvim-treesitter.configs'.setup {
 ignore_install = { "yaml" },
}

lvim.plugins = {
  { 'ikatyang/tree-sitter-yaml' }
}
```